# MongoDB getting $lookup to return only one record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is booking table

```
booking [
    {
        "_id" : "0J0DR",
        "user" : "MN90L",
        "property" : "58669471869659d70b424ea7",
        "checkin" : 1488758400,
        "checkout" : 1489363200
    },
    {
        "_id" : "0PDLR",
        "user" : "7CSEF",
        "property" : "586694ea869659d70b424eb3",
        "checkin" : 1488326400,
        "checkout" : 1498780800
    }
]
```

This is users table

```
users [
    {
        "_id" : "4M4KE",
        "email" : "test@vest.com",
        "name" : "Torben"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "MN90L",
        "email" : "mr@booker.com",
        "name" : "Mr. Booker"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "GF37A",
        "email" : "test@test.com",
        "name" : "Whatever"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "7CSEF",
        "email" : "miss@booker.com",
        "name" : "Miss. Booker"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "W0LG9",
        "email" : "xxx@yyy.com",
        "name" : "Whatever"
    }
]
```

And this is my query which works great, except every booking record gets ALL the users attached instead of just the users._id = booking.user

```
db.getCollection('booking').aggregate([{
    $match: {
        checkin : {$lte: (1512145439)},
        checkout: {$gte: (1483203600)},
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "users._id",
        foreignField: "booking.user",
        as: "users"
    }   
}, {
    $unwind: "$users"
}])
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried with and without the $unwind.

Do I need to do some $match or is the localField foreignField enough?

My db.version() = 3.2.12

Comment: Actually with the $unwind it creates one booking record for each user = 2 bookings x 5 users = 10 records in the result - and without $unwind it creates all users inside each booking record.

Comment: You have `localField` and `foreignField` mixed up. Try   `localField: "user",
        foreignField: "_id",`

Comment: @Veeram I tried both, but get the exact same result.  10 records (2 bookings x 5 users) .   This is really strange.

Comment: Its almost like if I wrote the field names wrong, or with wrong case or something, but I just cant see anything wrong with this.

Comment: It is strange. I ran your code with my suggested edits on 3.2.6 and it returns one matching user for each of the booking document.

Comment: And you are correct - your correction should work (according to their own documentation)  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: @Veeram I tried to run it on my big database, like you suggested, and without the $unwind it will put all users into each booking.  Check this:
https://db.tt/luNyIYPJHq

Comment: Can you try without the collection name/alias in the `localField` and `foreignField` ?

Comment: @Veeram that did it!!!  But.... why??   Is it because both users and booking has the "_id" as their unique identifier?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139894/discussion-between-torbenrudgaard-and-veeram).

Comment: No if you look at the docs. `localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>` are fields without alias or collection name.

Comment: @Veeram please post an answer - so others can find the solution when they have the same problem, and so I can give you credit :)

Comment: @Veeram since you been helping me so much with Mongo, i would like to repay the favor :)  Please contact me: torben at thaihome dot co dot uk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `localField` and `foreignField` mixed up.

Try `localField: "user", foreignField: "_id"` without the alias / collection name.

From docs

> localField: field from the input documents,
>   foreignField: field from the documents of the "from" collection,

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

When you use dot notation MongoDB thinks you are trying to access the fields from embedded documents.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation